# what will happen if lucene doc id exceed int

Tags: lucene

I'm building index on lucene, and I have 6 lucene indexs, number of docs in each index is less than INT_MAX, but total number of docs in 6 indexs will exceed INT_MAX, what will happen if I do searching on all 6 indexs? what will happen if one index exceed INT_MAX, crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id is considered for each index, so even if the total number of ids on the 6 indices will exceed the maximum, Lucene won't complain. However if you'll try to store a number too big for the datatype chosen (for instance a integer-64 squeezed in an integer-32 type), a Java error will be thrown. Best practice is to use a number represented as literal or even an alphanumeric value for your ids.